# pipenv: how to activate virtual environment by specifying name or path?

Tags: python, virtualenv, pipenv, pyenv, python-poetry

`pipenv` has a design centered around projects having their own venvs. What if I have a generic venv that I want to use for scripting or to be shared with other projects and therefore I would like it to be activate while the current directory is pointing anywhere in the system. How can I achieve this? I looked up the docs and I couldn't see a way to do it.

In conda, one can simply activate an environment by specifying its name, no matter whats the current directory is. Even `virtualenv` can do the same but you have to specify the path.

Answer (score 2):

At the directory where Pipfile resides, find the path to the environment:

```
pipenv --venv
```

Copy that path, for example /Users/yourname/.local/share/virtualenvs/yourproject-7qj8f3ed.  Then in any other folder you can activate the venv with `source`, e.g.:

```
source /Users/yourname/.local/share/virtualenvs/yourproject-7qj8f3ed/bin/activate
```

You could also put an alias in bash.rc, etc to make a shortcut to that command.